# How to stop "rsyslogd" and "systemd-journal" high cpu usage in debian 11 minimal?

Tags: linux, debian, linux-kernel

I'm running Debian 11 minimal I observed that `rsyslogd & systemd-journal` are taking 100% of cpu usage what will be the reason and how to stop the same?

```
 1599 root      20   0   54128  24832   2396 S 109.2   5.3   1:06.98 rsyslogd                                                             
  935 root      20   0   29108   5872   5200 R  42.9   1.3   0:26.99 systemd-journal
```

Any help will be really appreciated!

Comment: What can you say about the flow of `journalctf -f`? Is it static or you're getting many pages of output every second? If it's the latter maybe you could identify the "bad" service which generates so much log output and deal with it.

Comment: As a first step, you don't really need `rsyslog` on a systemd system like Debian 11. You can just remove it (`sudo apt purge rsyslog`). Then check what's hogging your journal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to @Artem S. Tashkinov I tried the command `journalctf -f` and i observed the following logs

```
[  107.041208] export_store: status -16
[  108.441202] export_store: status -16
[  108.741202] export_store: status -16
[  110.314120] gpio-1023 (sysfs): gpiod_request: status -16
[  110.412046] gpio-1023 (sysfs): gpiod_request: status -16
[  110.412052] export_store: status -16
[  112.694120] export_store: status -16
[  125.412004] gpio-1023 (sysfs): gpiod_request: status -16
[  125.412011] export_store: status -16
[  125.934120] gpio-1023 (sysfs): gpiod_request: status -16
[  126.441204] export_store: status -16
[  133.141201] gpio-1023 (sysfs): gpiod_request: status -16
[  133.141208] export_store: status -16
[  133.241204] gpio-1023 (sysfs): gpiod_request: status -16
[  133.412015] gpio-1023 (sysfs): gpiod_request: status -16
[  133.412022] export_store: status -16
[  138.704120] export_store: status -16
[  139.341207] gpio-1023 (sysfs): gpiod_request: status -16
[  139.741203] gpio-1023 (sysfs): gpiod_request: status -16
[  144.412047] gpio-1023 (sysfs): gpiod_request: status -16
[  144.412054] export_store: status -16
[  145.341205] gpio-1023 (sysfs): gpiod_request: status -16
[  146.412061] gpio-1023 (sysfs): gpiod_request: status -16
[  146.412068] export_store: status -16
[  148.154120] export_store: status -16
[  148.412030] gpio-1023 (sysfs): gpiod_request: status -16
[  148.412037] export_store: status -16
[  150.534120] gpio-1023 (sysfs): gpiod_request: status -16
[  152.412049] gpio-1023 (sysfs): gpiod_request: status -16
[  152.412055] export_store: status -16
[  152.464120] gpio-1023 (sysfs): gpiod_request: status -16
```

Here I got to know that issue was with the gpio 1023.

So now I have disabled and its fine now.